# How to disable sending of HTTP header through C program by setting the appropriate value of CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER?

Tags: c, http

I want to send an XML message through HTTP post request but I don't want to send the HTTP header. It is possible to not send the header setting the value of CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER in a C program. I want to know how to do that.

Comment: I found a link where explanation is given for the curl library functions
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html